# loadhook function in web.py not working

Tags: python, web.py, webhooks

I was trying to experiment with the loadhook function in web.py, however I am not quite able to make it work. Here is my code:

```
import web

render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self, name):
        return render.base(name)


def test():
    print "damn"
    render.base("test")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
    app.add_processor(web.loadhook(test))
```

The base.html template is pretty simple which echoes back the "name" parameter.

What I understood from the [documentation](http://webpy.org/cookbook/application_processors) was that the loadhook function will be called before every request. But it doesn't seem to work. I have tried going to the homepage, another page etc. Neither do I see a print statement on my CMD, nor does the base template with the name test gets executed.

I tried running the same code with just the add_processor as well, but no luck.

Can anyone help me figure out how to run a function before a request happens on a page?

Also, I am assuming request only encompasses browser level requests. Is there any way to capture more via web.py? (such as call a function on keypress, mouse click etc.)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

loadhooks are called early in the processing and are used to either set configuration or intercept. For example, I implement a black list similar to the following:

```
def my_hook():
    # If requester's IP is in my blacklist, redirect his browser.
    if blacklist.in_blacklist(web.ctx.ip) and web.ctx.path != '/blacklist':
        raise web.seeother('/blacklist')

....
app.add_processor(web.loadhook(my_hook))
```

In your example, your `test` hook calls `render` (I'm guessing you're trying to render the test page?) Problem is `loadhooks` don't return data to the browser, so calling `render` here doesn't do what you want.

Couple other issues: you need to call `app.add_processor(web.loadhook(my_hook))` prior to calling `app.run()`, because the latter sets your polling loop & never returns.

As for your final question: to capture keypresses, etc. you need your javascript to send something to the server.... Everytime there's a keypress, do an ajax call to the server to log the action.

Python's powerful, but still can't read minds.